# Wireless Audio - Easy sharing of wireless audio signals (Logitech) - Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, us20130117693, logitech, wireless-audio

**AN OVERBROAD PATENT ON Wireless Audio** - This application from [Logitech](http://www.logitech.com) seeks to patent the idea of...Forwarding a media stream from a first media output device to a second media output device! 10 minutes of your time can help narrow US patent applications before they become patents.  [Follow @askpatents](https://twitter.com/AskPatents) on twitter to help.

**QUESTION** - Have you seen anything that was **published before 8/25/2011** that discusses:

> - Sharing a media stream between two media devices

If so, please submit evidence of prior art as an answer to this question.. We welcome multiple answers from the same individual.

**EXTRA CREDIT** - A reference to anything that meets all of the criteria to the question above AND ALSO terminates the first media stream when it is transferred to a second media device

**TITLE: EASY SHARING OF WIRELESS AUDIO SIGNALS**

**Summary**:  [Translated from Legalese into English] A user commands (with voice, button, gesture, anything) a first media output device (e.g. an iPhone) to stream to a second media output device (e.g. a TV)

- **Publication Number**: [US20130117693 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130117693?dq=US20130117693A1)
- **Application Number**: US 13/567,203
- **Assignee**: Logitech
- **Prior Art Date**: Seeking prior Art **predating** 8/25/2011
- **Open for Challenge at USPTO:** Open through 11/5/2013

**Claim 1** requires each and every step below:

> A method comprising:
>
> 1. receiving, at a first media output device, streaming media from a media source device;
> 2. receiving, at the first media output device, a command by motion or voice to share the streaming media with a second media output device; and
> 3. initiating, by the first media output device, sharing of the streaming media between the first media output device and the second media output device.

In English this means:

> A method, comprising:
>
> 1. Streaming media to a media output device
> 2. Receiving a command to transfer the streaming media to a second media output device
> 3. Streaming the media from the first media output device to the second media output device

Good prior art would be evidence of a system that did each and every one of these steps prior to 8/25/2011

You're probably aware of ten pieces of art that meet this criteria already... separately, the applicant is claiming A reference to anything that meets all of the criteria to the question above AND ALSO where the first media output stream is terminated when it is streaming to a second media device

---

**"easy sharing of media from one media output device from a first user to a media output device of a second userfrom the Applicant"**

[image]

---

*What is good prior art? Please see our [FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#prior-art).*

*Want to help? Please vote or comment on submissions below. We welcome you to [post your own request for prior art](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prior-art-request+pre-grant) on other questionable US Patent Applications.*

---

Answer (score 2):

Apple's AirPlay technology/branding (September 1, 2010) seems to fit the bill. One can stream audio/visual streams, for example YouTube/NetFlix/etc to iPhone/iPad to AppleTV. Unfortunately I have been unable to find a document detailing everything, but I have identified some Apple patents that may apply:

- [GESTURE VISUALIZATION AND SHARING BETWEEN ELECTRONIC DEVICES](http://appft1.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PG01&p=1&u=/netahtml/PTO/srchnum.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=%2220120262379%22.PGNR.&OS=DN/20120262379&RS=DN/20120262379) (April 12, 2011)
- [system for allowing a media player to transfer digital audio to an accessory](http://www.google.com/patents/US7895378?dq=media%20streaming%20devices%20inassignee%3a%22Apple%20Inc.%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pVABUrScBoOBygGj1oGgBw&ved=0CGsQ6AEwCDhG) (Jun 27, 2006)
- [Methods and apparatuses for transferring streaming multimedia...within a network](http://www.google.com/patents/US7653685?dq=media%20streaming%20devices%20inassignee%3a%22Apple%20Inc.%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=e1ABUsCoCYrXyAGn2YEg&ved=0CGQQ6AEwBzgy) (Feb 15, 2006)
- [Method and apparatus for assisting with playback of remotely stored media files](http://appft1.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PG01&p=1&u=/netahtml/PTO/srchnum.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=%2220050108320%22.PGNR.&OS=DN/20050108320&RS=DN/20050108320) (May 19, 2005)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it was preceded by http://www.google.com/patents/WO2006133764A8 "A method for establishing a paired connection between media devices"

> "
>   **ABSTRACT** 
>   A method for establishing a paired connection between first and second media devices >across a network includes transmitting
>   a first information message across the network including an identifier
>   that includes a request to pair the first and second media devices.
>   When a second information message is received from the second media
>   device within a first predetermined time period, the first device
>   retrieves an identifier of the second device and transmits a
>   confirmation message across the network including the device
>   identifiers. A paired connection between the media devices is
>   completed after a corresponding confirmation message from the second
>   device is received within a second predetermined time period."

Answer (score 1):

Does this count:
https://sonos.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/126/kw/mesh

It mentions a mesh network between separate Sonos devices.
The date published mentions 05/13/2004, but the document has been updated in 01/07/2013.

The picture of the mesh network:
https://www.sonos.com/graphics/rn/FAQ126/SonosNet-wireless.PNG
is dated as modified on 17 July 2008 16:43:45.

Answer (score 1):

VLC media player has had this functionality for many, many years (very handy to do multi-room audio at parties for no cost!). See (dated 2005):
http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/

The page linked above demonstrates all of the three required criteria for prior art but does takes some reading to fathom. The first page I found that walks you through it I've linked to below, dated 2009:
https://github.com/videolan/vlc/commits/66d45378d23e7420a5facdcebf83aab95459a3fc/modules/gui/macosx/wizard.h

VLC is open source and stored on GIT, as such it's trivial to confirm at the code level when a feature was added, to help a little the code for the wizard (in Mac) has a header file with a date starting in 2005:
https://github.com/videolan/vlc/commits/66d45378d23e7420a5facdcebf83aab95459a3fc/modules/gui/macosx/wizard.h

Answer (score 1):

Windows Media Player version 12, released in 2009, has the Play To functionality, which does precisely this. See this Wikipedia Article. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Player.